# Change layout using a spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm trying to change the layout of my activity according to my selection inside the spinner.
But after the first selection, the spinner become white and I'm not able to decide another selection.
The code I'm using is the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinner;
String[] options = { "Modulo1", "Modulo2" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, options);
    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

int check = 0;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    check = check + 1;
    if (check > 1) {
        int selState = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        switch (selState) {
        case 0:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            break;
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity2_main);

            break;

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

//
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you need this **check**?

Comment: if you mean the check variable is used to show the selected item only after selecting an item from the drop down list.

Comment: you can simply use int variable from override method of spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner you are referring to is in your first activity. After you have replaced the content, the spinner isn't there anymore. If you have another spinner in the second layout, you have to reconnect it and set the listener again.
Basically you have to run your onCreate stuff after every setContentView...

As a side note, whatever you are trying to do, this is probably not the way to go. To show another full layout, better use another activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I saw that is not recommended to change the layout in the same activity. Probably the best solution should be to create a listview with all the possibility and create an activity with a different layout for each option.
What do you think?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. You can do it this way, have one activity with the list of options and open different activities from there. Or you might want to look into fragments, these are UI parts in an activity which can be replaced at runtime.