# Are Spinner recommended for layout change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I was thinking about using spinners (as it is like a dropdown feature) to change the type of text on my activity. For example let us say we choose the car from the spinner, it would change/replace the layout completely and show the car attributes e.g. car make. Another example is if the user click "Mobile" the spinners will change the layout on the activity.

Is this a good approach to take? Or is it best to create a activity for each product? The only reason I asked this as one of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294576/change-layout-using-a-spinner-in-android) recommended its not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are the only one that can decide whether to do that or not which mainly depends on the amount of changes that you will make to your layout events handling, and about `spinner` it has nothing to do with this manner, you will have to do an action after choosing an item from the `spinner` either creating a `new intent()` and launching an `activity` or changing the layout.

**So**, if you have minor changes in your "layout events handling", you have two options:

1. if the layout changes mainly in *sources*, *backgrounds*, and
   *visibility* of the layout-elements but the structure remains as it is, your best choice is to just make your changes to the `views`(elements)
   itself without changing the whole layout.
2. if the layout structure has to be changed, you are advised to change
   the whole layout by using the method:

   `setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);`

   and after that you have to
   declare the layout elements again.

**BUT**, if you have a complete new layout for every element in the `spinner`, you have two options:

1. create an `activity` for each element of the `spinner`, and include the `spinner` in each activity of them.
2. create a [fragment activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and include the `spinner` in the main
   layout of the `activity`, and create a `fragment` for each element in
   the `spinner`, and with each element change, navigate to it's
   corresponding `fragment`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!